# Converting string to ASCII number

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a function using Excel VBA to convert a string to its respective ASCII number. For example:

```
"ABCD" => "65666768"
```

I have written this code but it's failed to do the conversion:

```
Public Function asciien(s As String) As String
' Returns the string to its respective ascii numbers
   Dim i As Integer

   For i = 1 To Len(s)
      asciien = asciien & CStr(Asc(Mid(s, x, 1)))
   Next i 

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
asciien = asciien & CStr(Asc(Mid(s, x, 1)))
```

should read

```
asciien = asciien & CStr(Asc(Mid(s, i, 1)))
```

"x" has no value

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. It tried the code again but it still gives me "#NAME" value error.

Comment: Check that you have the function name spelled right on the sheet and also that the code for the function is not in a sheet object, it should be in its own module

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to enable the macro. Now the problem is resolved. Thank you very much!